# Reduce Blackberry Simulator load time

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Is there any way to reduce Blackberry simulator load time. One way I found was View->Turn Graphics Acceleration->off . We have to close the simulator every time we make a change in code. Is there any way to bypass this closing and restarting problem of BB simulators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a newer SDK (e.g. version 7) for development which does not require restarting the simulator every time while debugging. Then when you are ready just compile it to a target platform -- you can even do that from command line, of course always test it on the device before deployment.

Comment: ber4444 : Can you provide me with link to SDKv7.0

Comment: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp, they ship packages that contain Eclipse itself, after you install make sure you click "Check for Updates" within Eclipse.

Comment: You don't need the latest SDK to get this functionality. The Blackberry plugin for Eclipse has supported hot swapping apps in simulators for awhile.